# Прокинуть файл /etc/hosts в контейнер dokku

Tags: docker, dokku

Подскажите пожалуйста, есть приложение dokku c кучей работающих контейнеров docker.
Необходимо спробросить в эти контейнеры файл с локальной машины /etc/hosts c определенной конфигурацией.
Как можно это сделать?

Comment: пользовались ли вы поиском? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22907231/how-to-copy-files-from-host-to-docker-container

Comment: @Dmitry ваша ссылка, применима для контейнеров docker без управления dokku!

Comment: В этом и есть большая разница. При управление dokku любой update удаляет старые контейнеры и создает новые.
https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/#add-entries-to-container-hosts-file---add-host
https://docs.docker.com/network/network-tutorial-standalone/#use-user-defined-bridge-networks
https://dokku.com/docs/advanced-usage/persistent-storage/
https://github.com/alfetopito/dokku-hosts-plugin
Задачу  решил добавлением плагина https://github.com/mediascopegroup/dokku-hosts